# How to input a number with 0 and decimal in C and do its sine?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm currently doing a C course and I have to make a program that prints the sine function for an input x between (0, 1). The thing is, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
double x;
double result = 0;

printf("Input a number betwen 0 and 1: ");
scanf("%.f", x);

result = sin(x);

printf("\aThe sine of %.8f is %.8f\n", x, result);

system("pause>null");
return 0;
```

This is the code I wrote; when I try to input 0.5 the machine returns me a "The sine of 0.00000 is 0.0000", but if I declare the variable as 0.5, the program works fine and gives me the correct answer. The error appears when I try to use `scanf` to input the number, and the activity says I have to input it.

I looked in the internet and I can't find anything, I'm a newbie in this world, I started about 2 weeks ago.

Comment: You ought to be getting compiler warnings about the scanf line. If you're not, work out how to turn them on as they'll be useful in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two fundamental problems with your `scanf("%.f", x);` line. First, the `%.f` format specifier is wrong: the `.` is not valid for input of this sort, and a `double` value requires the `l` (lowercase L) prefix - so use `%lf`.

Second, the argument corresponding to that format specifier must be the *address* of a suitable (`double`) variable.

So, use `scanf("%lf", &x);` and your program will work.

Answer (score 0):

**Enable warnings**

`double x; scanf("%.f", x);` should have warned as `"%f"` expects a matching `float *`, not a `double`.

Use `"%lf"` to read a `double`.

Even better, check the `scanf()` return value to insure valid input occurred.

```
if (scanf("%lf", &x) == 1) {
  result = sin(x);
  printf("\aThe sine of %.8f is %.8f\n", x, result);
}
```

Comment: Actually, `%.f` doesn't expect *any* matching argument. For example, **clang-cl** gives: *warning : invalid conversion specifier '.' [-Wformat-invalid-specifier]*